# How to adjust test helper to account for from which model the test user is (metaprogramming)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've followed [Hartl's chapter 8](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-test_helper_log_in) to develop a log_in_as test helper. Now I wanted to do some metaprogramming by adding type as a parameter. Type specifies which model the user is from. There are two models (Member and Organization) each of which can log in using the same page / create method (through if-else statement).

However, for an integration test the test is not working. The test always sees the user as coming from the model Organization and never from Member. What am I doing wrong?

I have the following **test helper**:

```
  def log_in_as(type, user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    ### Additional if-else statement needed for type? ###
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      if type == "mem_ber"
        session[:member_id] = user.id
      elsif type == "org_anization"
        session[:organization_id] = user.id
      end
    end
  end

  def is_logged_in_member?
    !session[:member_id].nil?
  end

  def is_logged_in_organization?
    !session[:organization_id].nil?
  end

  private
    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
```

The **integration test**:

```
require 'test_helper'
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @admin         = members(:michael)
    @non_admin     = members(:archer)
    @org_admin     = organizations(:one)
    @org_nonadmin  = organizations(:two)
  end

  test "ff" do
    log_in_as("mem_ber", @admin)
    puts "member: #{is_logged_in_member?}"
    puts "organization: #{is_logged_in_organization?}"
    delete logout_path

    log_in_as("mem_ber", @non_admin)
    puts "member: #{is_logged_in_member?}"
    puts "organization: #{is_logged_in_organization?}"
    delete logout_path

    log_in_as("org_anization", @org_admin)
    puts "member: #{is_logged_in_member?}"
    puts "organization: #{is_logged_in_organization?}"
    delete logout_path

    log_in_as("org_anization", @org_nonadmin)
    puts "member: #{is_logged_in_member?}"
    puts "organization: #{is_logged_in_organization?}"
    delete logout_path
  end
end
```

Def create in the sessions controller is:

```
  def create
    @organization = Organization.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    @member = Member.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @organization && @organization.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if @organization.activated?
        log_in("org_anization", @organization)
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember("org_anization", @organization) : forget("org_anization", @organization)
        redirect_back_or @organization
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    elsif @member && @member.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if @member.activated?
        log_in("mem_ber", @member)
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember("mem_ber", @member) : forget("mem_ber", @member)
        redirect_back_or @member
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

For all four `log_in_as` tests in the test file, it says `is_logged_in_member?` false and `is_logged_in_organization?` true, so also if it is actually a fixture coming from members.yml. I've also tried adding

```
  self.set_fixture_class organizations: Organization
  self.set_fixture_class members: Member
```

to the test helper, but that made no difference.

If I remove organizations from the test (in `def setup` as well as remove 2 of the four tests) it still produces the same result in that it sees the member users as organizations. Only when I also empty the organizations fixtures file, it sees the members as members.

Comment: You said both types login from the same page/create method, so how does that form determine the user's type? If it's just a parameter, you could add it to the session parameters you pass to `post login_path`. If it's determined on the backend, then I'd think this would work as is.

Comment: I've added the sessions controller. Not sure how to pass the parameter to `post login_path`...

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't with your `log_in_as` method, but rather the fact that `Usertype2.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)` is returning a user from the `Usertype1` fixture. Is the `Usertype2` fixture separate from the `Usertype1` fixture, or are you specifying the type as an attribute of a more generic `User`?

Comment: Yes, I have a usertype1.yml as well as a usertype2.yml.  On the development server it works correctly: then usertype1 is treated as such and the same applies to usertype2. Its only with the tests that there are problems. So, I think this would imply that the problem is not within `def create`...

Comment: Seems like the problem is in the communication between your fixtures and the `create` method (since create is returning an instance of `Usertype1` when you're calling `find` on `Usertype2`). One simple thing worth checking is if the behavior changes if you change the names of the fixture files to be plural. If not, I'd try explicitly setting the class each fixture references (see "When model name and table name does not match" at  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2014/09/21/tricks-and-tips-for-using-fixtures-in-rails.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause: it turned out that in both fixtures files there was an instance with the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

In `test_helper.rb`:

```
self.set_fixture_class usertype1: Usertype1
self.set_fixture_class usertype2: Usertype2
```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately with the same outcome.